# Splitting nested lists into DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data:

```
{
    "load_avg_1min": "0.40",
    "load_avg_5min": "0.25",
    "load_avg_15min": "0.28",
    "processes_total": "719",
    "processes_running": "3",
    "cpu_state_user": "34.19",
    "cpu_state_kernel": "10.36",
    "cpu_state_idle": "55.44",
    "TABLE_cpu_usage": {
        "ROW_cpu_usage": [
            {
                "cpuid": "0",
                "user": "32.98",
                "kernel": "11.34",
                "idle": "55.67"
            },
            {
                "cpuid": "1",
                "user": "34.37",
                "kernel": "10.41",
                "idle": "55.20"
            }
        ]
    },
    "memory_usage_total": "8159468",
    "memory_usage_used": "4310284",
    "memory_usage_free": "3849184",
    "vm_total": "0",
    "vm_free": "0",
    "mem_buffers": "130460",
    "mem_cached": "2480340",
    "current_memory_status": "OK"
}
```

Im looking to create a single row DataFrame. However, I want each element of `ROW_cpu_usage` to be a different column i.e:

```
cpuid.0 | user.0 ... cpuid.1 etc etc
```

Im currently using the below but unable to see any clean ways of using the `meta` or `record_path` arguments.

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data=json_payload)
```

EDIT: The DF should also include the other data from `data` such as `load_avg_1min` etc.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Using json_normalize() and pivot():

```
df = pd.json_normalize(
    data= json_payload,
    meta=[x for x in json_payload.keys() if x != "TABLE_cpu_usage"],
    record_path=["TABLE_cpu_usage", "ROW_cpu_usage"],
    record_prefix="record_"
)

df = df.pivot(index=[x for x in df.columns if not x.startswith("record_")], columns="record_cpuid")
df.columns = [".".join(x).split("_")[-1] for x in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  load_avg_1min load_avg_5min load_avg_15min processes_total processes_running cpu_state_user cpu_state_kernel cpu_state_idle memory_usage_total memory_usage_used memory_usage_free vm_total vm_free mem_buffers mem_cached current_memory_status user.0 user.1 kernel.0 kernel.1 idle.0 idle.1
0          0.40          0.25           0.28             719                 3          34.19            10.36          55.44            8159468           4310284           3849184        0       0      130460    2480340                    OK  32.98  34.37    11.34    10.41  55.67  55.20
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry edit made to question.

Comment: see edit, added meta columns

Comment: thanks but it seems this names all the columns either .1 or .0 instead of the keys just under `"ROW_cpu_usage"`

Comment: see edit only added id on record_path columns.